# How do I create a snippet that optiionally expands multiple lines using YASnippet(or some other tool)?

Tags: yasnippet

I know how to create basic snippets using YASnippet.

For example, consider the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: js-function
# key: jsfunc
# --
/** @function
 * @name ${1:fn-name}
 * @description ${2:description}
 * @param  {${3:type}} ${4:name} ${5:desc}
 * @returns {${6:type}} ${7:desc}
 */

const $1 = exports.$1 = ($4) => {
      
};
```

This works very well, as intended.

I would like to do the following two more things:

- Keep the number of @params dynamic, and have YASnippet use the tab-stop fields 'type', 'name' and 'description' for each, and then mirroring the 'name'(s) in a comma separated list (using mirrored field transformations perhaps?).
  *I know YASnippet supports embedded elisp, but since I am a noob, I can't really figure out if there is some obvious way to do this using elisp.*
- Automatically insert a '* ' for every line automatically if I insert a multi-line ${2:description} *This could in theory be implemented easily if the above functionality is possible. I am currently doing this by <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>`, however it would be nice if this can be done using YASnippet*

Following expanded code is what I would like to achieve dynamically:

```javascript
/** @function
 * @name generateDSAKey
 * @description Generate a DSA Keypair
 * @param  {int} keysize keysize of the DSA
 * @param {function} cb callback function 
 * @returns {undefined}
 */

const generateDSAKey = exports.generateDSAKey = (keysize, cb) => {
    
};
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated

Comment: Elisp tag is only for questions about elisp as lenguage itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad. First time posting here.